# private clause with loop iterators and omp simd

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

When I try this

```
#pragma omp simd private(i)
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
```

with GCC 5.2.1 I get the error

```
error: iteration variable ‘i’ should not be private
```

I get the same error for `firstprivate` and `lastprivate` as well.  I discovered this from this code

```
int i;
#pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:sum) lastprivate(i)
for(i=0; i<(n/8)*8; i++) sum += a[i];
for(; i<n; i++) sum += a[i];
```

However, this works fine

```
int i,j;
#pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:sum) lastprivate(j)
for(i=0; i<(n/8)*8; i++) {sum += a[i]; j=i;}
for(; j<n; j++) sum += a[j];
```

but that seems like a silly hack.

GCC also gives me the warning

```
warning: ‘i’ may be used uninitialized in this function
```

with `parallel for simd` but no warning when only using `parallel for`.

Why can't I explicitly declare the parallel loop iterator as `private` with `omp simd` or `omp for simd`? Isn't it implicitly `private` anyway?

---

From the OpenMP 4.0 specification section 14.1.2 recommended in Hristo Iliev's answer.

> The loop iteration variable in the associated for-loop of a simd construct with just one associated for-loop may be listed in a linear clause with a constant-linear-step
>   that is the increment of the associated for-loop.
>
> The loop iteration variables in the associated for-loops of a simd construct with multiple associated for-loops may be listed in a lastprivate clause.

This works

```
int i;
#pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:sum) linear(i)
for(i=0; i<(n/8)*8; i++) sum += a[i];
for(; i<n; i++) sum += a[i];
```

but it appears `linear(i)` is not needed either so the iterator is by default `linear(i)`.

So I could just have done

```
 #pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:sum)
```

It appears the iterator is effectively `lastprivate` by default with `omp simd` and `omp for simd`.

I still get a warning

```
‘i’ may be used uninitialized in this function
```

---

I should have picked section 14.1.1

> Certain variables and objects have predetermined data-sharing attributes as follows:
>
> The loop iteration variable in the associated for-loop of a **simd** construct with just one associated for-loop is linear with a constant-linear-step that is the increment of the associated for-loop.

---

Here is a working example which gives the warning with `-fopenmp` but no warning without `-fopenmp`

```
‘i’ may be used uninitialized in this function
```

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#define N 101                                                                                                       
float foo(float *a, int n)
{
    float sum = 0;
    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:sum)
    for(i=0; i<(n/8)*8; i++) sum += a[i];
    for(; i<n; i++) sum += a[i];
    return sum;
}

int main(void) {
    const int N = 101;
    float a[N]; for(int i=0; i<N; i++) a[i] = i;
    printf("%f\n", foo(a,N));
}
```

Comment: The iterator in your case is **predetermined** to be `linear`. Having a predetermined class is much stronger than having an implicitly determined data-sharing class as predetermined classes can only be overridden in some cases. The warning about `i` being used uninitialised probably comes from the semantics of `linear`, which assigns to each SIMD lane's private copy of `i` the value of `i0 + iteration*linear_step`, where `i0` is the value of `i` before the SIMD construct.

Comment: @HristoIliev, thank you. I see I picked the wrong section. I should have picked section 2.14.1.1 like you said in your answer. I updated my question. It's not clear to me in the specification that `linear` is like `lastprivate` but that's what I observe in the code. I wonder what the motivation was for introducing `linear`? Why not make `(first)(last)private` obsolete and just use `linear` e.g. for the iterator in `parallel for`?

Comment: Section 2.14.3.7: _"The value corresponding to the sequentially last iteration of the associated loops is assigned to the original list item."_ is what makes `linear` similar to `lastprivate`. Still `lastprivate` also works with sections, while `linear` is specifically designed to support the abstract model of SIMD. You should turn to the OpenMP language committee for an actual explanation.

Comment: Could you please post a MWE that produces the warning about `i`? I cannot  seem to be able to reproduce it using GCC 5.2.0 and the code fragments from your question.

Comment: @HristoIliev, okay, I reproduced it and added the MWE to the end of my question. I think it's complaining that `(n/8)*8` could me `<=0` but I don't get this warning when I don't compile with `-fopenmp` or when I only use `parallel for` and not `parallel for simd`.

Comment: Sorry, I tried every possible combination of `-fopenmp`, `-fopenmp-simd`, `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, `-std=c99`, and different optimisation options but GCC 5.2.0 is not complaining. Also, the intermediate tree dumps show that GCC inserts `i = 0;` before the SIMD-ised loop.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I tried the MWE in GCC 4.9.2 and I don't get a warning but in GCC 5.2.1 I do. Note that you're using 5.2.0 so I guess that's the only difference.  I used `gcc -O3 -Wall -fopenmp mwe.c`

Comment: Compile with `-O3 -Wall -fopenmp -fdump-tree-all` (warning: produces a fair amount of files in the current directory) and examine the intermediate representations after the OpenMP lowering and expansion for absence of initialisation of `i` before the loop. It is either a regression or a result of an overly aggressive optimisation.

Comment: I just showed in my test suite that gcc 5.4 remains buggy in implementation of omp simd reduction lastprivate.  The same case is working correctly with recent gcc 6, 7.1, and Intel icc.  Of course, it works correctly in older gcc if #pragma omp simd is removed.  Typically, the simd clause doesn't do anything useful in gcc when added to parallel et asl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, loop iteration variables in `simd` constructs with a single associated for-loop have predetermined data-sharing class `linear` and not `private` ([OpenMP 4.0](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf), §2.14.1.1). `linear` provides functionality that is a superset of `private` and therefore declaring `i` as `(last)private` is a downgrade, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I updated my question based on your answer. It seems that `linear(i)` is implicit so I don't even need it. The iterator is effectively lastprivate by default with `simd`. I'm still getting the warning "‘i’ may be used uninitialized in this function"